# Function handling across multiple datagridviews with minimal duplicate code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have 10 datagridviews in a tabcontrol that require the same additional functions like copy/paste to be coded in.  The code is fairly long to cover these and I'm trying to minimize the amount of duplicate code used.

My current method is to take the "object sender" from a form item event (such as KeyDown) and pass it to a single function handler method where it is cast to a "DataGridView" object.  Then any cell selections and values can be modified using that DataGridView object.

Casting the "object" to a "DataGridView" seems crude.  Will this cause any referencing issues down the road?  Does this impose any odd limitations?  Is there a more "widely used" programming practice to accomplish this task?

**Function Handling**

```
private void dgv01_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    dgv_KeyDown_Handler(sender, e);
}

private void dgv02_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    dgv_KeyDown_Handler(sender, e);
}

private void dgv03_KeyDown 
....

private void dgv_KeyDown_Handler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgvHandler = (DataGridView)sender;

    // Handles ctrl+c/ctrl+v using dgvHandler to modify cell values
}
```

Comment: Simplest is to point KeyDown event of all the DataGridViews to the single event handler `dgv_KeyDown_Handler`

Comment: Is there a shorter way to point the KeyDown event of each DataGridView to the single event handler other than how I have it above?

Comment: Yes, just create one event handler, and use it for all data grids. You can do that be choosing the same event handler for all grids in the property grid of each one.

Comment: _Casting the "object" to a "DataGridView" seems crude_ Not at all. This is  a common and recommended pattern.

Comment: As for other, non-event driven methods, I usually create (static) functions with nice names into which I pass all they need; in this case obviously the DGV and then what ever else is needed..